# How to add metadata to a test using Google Test / How to send data from a Google Test to a TestEventListener

Tags: c++, googletest

Let me explain. I'm currently working on setting up an autograder for programming assignments at my school. We are using [Gradescope](https://gradescope-autograders.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for the autograding infrastructure. Skipping through the details, Gradescope expects that after running the test cases a JSON file will be populated with their schema.

Now, here's where I'm struggling. I decided that the best way to set this up is by using [Gtest Event Listeners](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md#extending-googletest-by-handling-test-events). This will allow me to get information about the tests as they are running and start creating the JSON. However, for Gradescope to work, I need some information other than whether the tests passed or failed. For instance, I need to know what that particular test is worth in the context of the assignment, or what name it will show on Gradescope, and so on and so forth. One way to deal with this issue could be to store that meta-information in a YAML file that will be read by my listener. However, I would like to stay away from that since it requires the user to carefully set up the YAML so that test names match and it becomes, in general, more prone to error by the user (i.e. instructors setting up the assignment).

Ideally, I would like an API that keeps this metadata together with the tests. I was envisioning something like `GRADED_TEST(TestSuite, TestName, /*weight=*/10, /*name=*/"Gradescope Test!", ...)` that would replace the `TEST`/`TEST_F` macros provided by GTest. However, I found that this is quite hard to do since there is no easy way (as far as I can tell), to send information from the Test object to the TestEventListener. Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

(I do not intent this to be an answer but I cannot comment yet.)

Can you create a naming scheme for your test case to include such information?

For example: `TEST(TestSuite, TestName_weight_10_name_GradescopeTest)`
Google Test's document does not encourage the use of underscore for the test name, but it's working fine.